# Next.js: Get back to old scroll position on back button WITHOUT affecting the other/next page scroll?

Tags: scroll, next.js

Is there a possibility in next.js to get back to old scroll position on back button WITHOUT affecting the other/next page scroll?

The solution I tried is working but not without affecting the next page scroll position and also the next page affecting the previous/back button page scroll postion.

So if i do not scroll on next page and go back it's fine, but I scroll on next page and get back the position of back page(original page) is not the same
What I tried:

- Update next.config.js with:

  ```
    experimental: {
       modern: true,
       scrollRestoration: true,
    }
  ```
- Switched scroll prop to false for SiteLink component which wraps Link from next:
  `<SiteLink href={slug} scroll={false} />`
- Attach and remove scroll event listener on page I want scroll to be remebered:

  ```
   const state = useContext(ScrollContext);

   useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0, state.scrollPos);

     const handleScrollPos = () => {
       state.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
     };

     window.addEventListener('scroll', () => handleScrollPos());

     return () => {
       // remove event listener on unmount
       window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => handleScrollPos());
   };
  ```

  `}, []);`

  Scroll Context

````
    import { createContext } from 'react';

    const state = {
       scrollPos: 0,
    };
    const ScrollContext = createContext(state);

    export default ScrollContext;```
````